# Chrome dev tools & visibility:hidden work around?

Tags: google-chrome, visibility, google-chrome-devtools

On my page I have a bunch of full screen iframes that I set to `visibility:hidden` when not needed.

In Chrome dev-tools, if I right-click > inspect element, the top z-Indexed of these iframes gets "selected" in the elements tab of dev tools (even though it is hidden).

In firebug the selection does not see hidden objects, (same as what the user sees)

Is there away to get devtools to not "see" those hidden iframes the way firebug does?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a DevTools bug. I reported it [here](http://crbug.com/328856). Meanwhile, try setting `display: none` on all iframes by calling:

```
var frames = document.querySelectorAll('iframe');
for(var i=0, l=frames.length; i<l; i++) {
  if( getComputedStyle(frames[i]).visibility === 'hidden' ) {
   frames[i].style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

Comment: Changing the code to accommodate a tool does not really help as that will break the page. Thanks for reporting the bug.